# jQuery blind effect doesn't work correctly in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I've got this bit of css/javascript/html that uses jQuery 1.5 and jQuery-ui 1.8.9. It's a fairly basic view. A top panel of metadata that pertains to the stuff in a lower div. The top panel opens and closes using the "blind" effect.

Here is the code snippet: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CTxB7/)

Everything works fine on Chrome & firefox. On IE it doesn't "blind" open...it just toggles to visible. When closing it, it blinds closed but then the entire page flashes once.

I don't know why this happens. I can find no references to such behavior in my searches. It's possible my Google-fu is weak today.

Anyone have any ideas on how to make it play nice in IE? Unfortunately I can't mandate that we don't support I.E.

Comment: Works fine in IE8 for me. Fails in IE7 compatability.

Comment: I should say it doesn't work on IE9. Thank you for checking those other ones for me, I appreciate it...

Comment: The animation looks the same to me in Opera 11 and IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position: relative` attribute from '.toggle-handle' in the CSS. Seems to solve things for me.

Incidentally, you can hide the `#hideable-content` div in CSS and simplify your JavaScript code to the following:

```
$(function() {
    // set effect from select menu value
    $("#toggle-handle").click(function() {
        $("#hideable-content").slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CTxB7/11/

Comment: excellent :) I also discovered what the overarching issue was...I forgot the doctype in the actual code...so IE was putting it into quirks mode. You led me down the path to checking this and this answer is also helpful so incoming checkmark